# Upload de arquivos com Vue-Resource

Tags: vue.js

Galera como faço para fazer upload de imagem com o Vue-Resource!?

Já tentei de várias formas mas não consigo! Alguém tem um exemplo funcional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consegui!!

Segue alguém precisar:

```js
methods: {
  send() {
      let data = new FormData();

      data.append('file', this.record.file)
      this.$http.post('test', data);
    },
    upload(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var files = e.target.files;
      this.record.file = files[0];
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input @change="upload" type="file">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <button @click="send">Send</button>
</div>
```

No servidor basta dar um `dd($request->all())` que vai estar lá o arquivo!